# Handling a null / blank data in your mysql queries?

Tags: php, mysql, null

Suppose your form has some fields and some are just can be simply left blank by the user to be filled on later.

How do you guys handle it before handling it to your SQL query?

I'm still quite new to PHP and here's how I did it.

```
function checkVAR( $str )
{
  $val = htmlentities( $_REQUEST[$str] , ENT_QUOTES , "UTF-8" );
  if ( $val == "" )
    return "NULL";
  return "'" . $val . "'";
}
```

So later on my query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tblName ( idCol , col2 , col3 ) " .
  "VALUES (" . checkVAR('idcol') . "," . checkVAR('col2') . "," . checkVAR('col3') . ");"
```

I find my method to still quite tedious I wonder if there are other better ways of handling this kind of situation. This function of mine does not do well on returning numbers so I had a separate function that does the quite the same except that it return `0` instead of `null`.

Comment: @Hindol Comments like that make me want to downvote comments.  Not learn DB stuff?  The database holds your application and is more often then not gonna be the location of your app's performance issues and is most likely to yield performance increases.  That is awful advice.

Comment: @Hindol: What Charles said and but bugs in code are easy to fix, bugs in your data are often forever, this is why database people are so finicky about properly constraining your database with CHECKs and FKs and everything else they can get their hands on.

Comment: Oops, I'll delete my comment. I actually tried to recommend a MySQL independent way of writing queries. My wordings were wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should not be encoding HTML characters before you input data into the database.  What happens if you want that data to be sent via some non-HTML means of display?  It is probably gonna look like gobbledy gook.  You should be, at the very least, escaping string data and ensuring numeric data types are cast to the appropriate types.  Better yet would be to use prepared statements.

I'm going to assume that you're properly using the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extension because the older [`mysql_*` API has been deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are using the *improved* extension, right?  Right?  Ok!

```
function getNullOrEscaped($string)
{
    // casting ensures that we are passing a string to mysqli_real_escape_string
    // and allows us to pass objects with __toString implemented
    $string = (string) $string;
    return ($string === '') ? null : mysqli_real_escape_string($string);
}
```

However, I would probably look at using [prepared statements](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: I used `htmlentities()` assuming it would prevent SQL injections.  But I read in the php.net page of `mysqli_real_escape_string()` that it doesn't handle `%` and `_`.

Comment: `htmlentities()` would help prevent [Cross Site Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks, not SQL injection.

Answer (score -1):

This makes what you did prettier, and probably easier to use:

#### Functions page:

```
function check_post($var)
{
  $val = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
  return ($var== "") ? NULL : "'" . $var . "'";
}
```

#### Form handler:

```
$value = check_post($var);
$query = "INSERT INTO `table` (id, col1) VALUES (" . $value . ")";
```

However, you really should check other solutions. I *highly* recommend IDIORM, a simple database ORM (http://j4mie.github.com/idiormandparis/). This makes inserting values as easy as:

```
$object = ORM::for_table("table")->create();
$object->value = check_post($var);
$object->save();
```

Comment: -1 for HTML escaping before DB input and using a [deprecated MySQL extension](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: Jeez, I just copied the code he used, doesn't he probably want the HTML escaped beforehand?

Comment: I just took out the extension. How does that look?

Comment: @CharlesSprayberry I have to agree partially, `mysql_` isn't recommended for developing new applications but the compatibility is still there for older software, I think "deprecated" isn't the right word seeing as it's still supported in the latest version of PHP. It's just highly unrecommended and deprecated in most experienced developers' view, but PHP-wise it still works and is not deprecated. :)

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using `htmlentities()`?  @Archio I'll try that, though it might be tedious at the start but hey maybe in the long run I won't be bothering much in the stability since sometimes I got errors simply cause my function got trouble returning numbers. It's only good for strings.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté No, it is deprecated.  It clearly states in documentation that the extension is not supported and long-term deprecation has been announced.  Furthering the use of this old, security prone, *deprecated* extension ensures that it continues to live.

Comment: `long-term deprecation has been announced` Yes, but not yet nor the near future. I just wanted to mention that many sites still run on `mysql_` such as older PHPBB2 forums, and actually deprecating it would force those to stay with the current PHP version. I agree that PDO or (at least) `mysqli_` should be used for new applications.

Comment: Exactly my point, Fabrício. Not sure why you've down voted me for using `mysql_query`, so I changed it to suggesting an ORM that uses PDO.

Comment: @Archio The downvote was not only in relation to the use of `mysql_*` but also because HTML escaping database input is not a good idea.

Comment: Good then, I took out the HTML escaping. Other than that, it's a high quality answer. However I stand by the fact that long term deprecation **has not set in place and not in the near future**. It's still acceptable and in use. Just possibly not up to your personal coding standard.